# nestjs/mongoose Typeerror: Invalid schema configuration

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I'm looking for assistance, I've been trying to lift up a nest api with mongoose, I proceed to declare a simple schema with one property as is shown in nest docs, but I've come with this error and haven't found a way to fix it yet.

I declare my module-schema like this

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type PriceDocument = Price & Document;

@Schema()
export class Price {
  @Prop(Number)
  discount?: number;

  @Prop({
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  })
  netValue: number;
}

export const PriceSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Price);
```

and I continue getting the TypeError

```
TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type at path `netValue.required`
```

I'm using the following versions

```
"@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.2.0",
```

Comment: is this error show up when you want to add new data?

Comment: It shows when I run the api with npm start:dev